Distracting TouchEvent in NestedRecyclerView
I have a nested RecyclerView. I'll call them as ParentRecyclerView and ChildRecyclerView.
My goal is kind of complicated. 

If i click ParentRecyclerView's item, then the color of ParentRecyclerView's item bckground will be changed to gray.(It means the ParentRecyclerView gets the TouchEvent)
If i click ChildRecyclerView's item, then the effect is same with number 1. It means the color of parentRecyclerview's item will be changed to gray(clicked/touched, It means the ParentRecyclerView gets the TouchEvent like Number 1)
If i touch and drag the ChildRecyclerView Horizontally, then i can scroll the ChildRecyclerView.(It means the ParentRecylcerView doesn't get the TouchEvent. ChildRecyclerView gets the TouchEvent.) 
I used selector with XML to change the background of the item.
and I used TouchEvent to make it work the way I wanted it to and made a custom ConstraintLayout. 

Here is the code of custom ConstraintLayout.
class TouchThroughConstraintLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
    private var mLastMotionX = 0f
    private var mLastMotionY = 0f

    private lateinit var childViewGroup: ViewGroup

    fun setChildView(childViewGroup: ViewGroup) { // in this case, the childViewGroup is ChildRecyclerView
        this.childViewGroup = childViewGroup
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (ev.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mLastMotionX = ev.x
                mLastMotionY = ev.y
                return childViewGroup.isViewInBounds(ev.rawX.toInt(), ev.rawY.toInt())
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                return false
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    private fun View.isViewInBounds(x : Int, y :Int): Boolean{
        val outRect = Rect()
        val location = IntArray(2)

        getDrawingRect(outRect)
        getLocationOnScreen(location)
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1])

        return outRect.contains(x, y)
    }
}

but the code doesn't work because When i touch the childRecyclerView, isViewInBounds() always returns true. So, the ParentRecyclerView gets the TouchEvent. 
How can i solve it?? Thanks in advance. :)


Where did you use the custom constraint layout?

Made some modifications. Please check.
class TouchThroughConstraintLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?)
    : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
    private var mLastMotionX = 0f
    private var mLastMotionY = 0f

    private lateinit var childViewGroup: ViewGroup

    private val touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop

    fun setChildView(childViewGroup: ViewGroup) {
        this.childViewGroup = childViewGroup
    }

    private var childViewIsTouched = false
    private var childViewIsSwipedHorinzontally = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (ev.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mLastMotionX = ev.x
                mLastMotionY = ev.y
                // Check if the touch is within the bounds of the child view group
                childViewIsTouched = childViewGroup.isViewInBounds(ev.rawX.toInt(), ev.rawY.toInt())
                // Always intercept the touch event to handle it in onTouchEvent
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                childViewIsSwipedHorinzontally = false

                //Pass the event to the child view if child is touched
                if (childViewIsTouched) {
                    childViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
                }
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                //Pass the event to the child view if childView is touched Touched and swiped
                if (childViewIsTouched && isHorizontalSwipe(event)) {
                    childViewIsSwipedHorinzontally = true
                    childViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
                }

            }
            //If child view is not swiped consume the event
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                return if (!childViewIsSwipedHorinzontally) {
                    super.onTouchEvent(event)
                }else{
                    false
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun isHorizontalSwipe(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val adx = abs(event.x - mLastMotionX)
        return adx > touchSlop
    }

    private fun View.isViewInBounds(x : Int, y :Int): Boolean{
        val outRect = Rect()
        val location = IntArray(2)

        getDrawingRect(outRect)
        getLocationOnScreen(location)
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1])

        return outRect.contains(x, y)
    }

}


Edit: Also you have to remove android:state_pressed="true" portion of your sbg_white.xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#EAEAEA" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF1F1F1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
<!--    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF1F1F1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>


Add logic handling the selection state of parent RV item:
class ParentAdapter: ListAdapter<ParentItem, ParentAdapter.ParentViewHolder>(diffUtil) {

  private var selectedPosition = -1

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ParentViewHolder(binding).apply{
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                val previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition
                selectedPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition)
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
                true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //update selected state accordingly
        holder.itemView.isSelected = position == selectedPosition

        holder.bind()
    }

   //rest of your codes

}


If it's necessary to retain the other states of the rv item like the scroll position, you can do partial bind using change payload:
class ParentAdapter: ListAdapter<ParentItem, ParentAdapter.ParentViewHolder>(diffUtil) {

   companion object{
       private const val PAYLOAD_SELECTED_STATE = "selected_state"
   }

  private var selectedPosition = -1

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ParentViewHolder(binding).apply{
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                val previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition
                selectedPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition, PAYLOAD_SELECTED_STATE)
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition, PAYLOAD_SELECTED_STATE )
                true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: NewsViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        }else {
            for (payload in payloads) {         
                if (payload == PAYLOAD_SELECTED_STATE) {
                   //update selected state accordingly
                    holder.itemView.isSelected = position == selectedPosition
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //update selected state accordingly
        holder.itemView.isSelected = position == selectedPosition

        holder.bind()
    }

   //rest of your codes

}



The only problem is when i took my finger off, the touch effect still remains on the ParentItem and also when i scroll the child recylcerView, the touch effect shows up too. I don't want to make the touch effect on the parent layout(viewholder) when i scroll the child recyclerview! But it's really good code. I was inspired a lot. :)

In my test, the parent RV doesn't receive the click event when horizontal swiped is performed on the child RV.

I just changed the original custom constraintLayout to yours. What did i miss? Could you please show me your whole code with gist or something?

Swipe the rv horizontally and then take off your finger. the effect still remains on it.

I checked the rest of your implementation, it's caused by your sbg_white.xml selector.  Comment out or remove android:state_pressed="true" section. Please see updated answer.

I'm sorry if I confused you. I also need the effect. please check my original question.
I want the ParentViewholder to turn gray when i touch(click) anywhere, but I don't want to the ParentViewHolder to turn gray when i scroll the child rv.

You have to handle the updating the selected state of your parent recyclerview item via onClickListener.  Please check updated answer.

Finally! I made it!! Thank you ltp!! I really appreciate your effect for me. i'll upload my full code here. Thank you!!!!

@CodingBruceLee, you're welcome.  Also added option that can be useful to you in the updated answer. Appreciate if you can mark this as the answer.

EDITED:
Have made some changes to the gist provided by you:
class TouchThroughConstraintLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
    private var mLastMotionX = 0f
    private var mLastMotionY = 0f

    private lateinit var childViewGroup: ViewGroup

    fun setChildView(childViewGroup: ViewGroup) {
        this.childViewGroup = childViewGroup
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (ev.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mLastMotionX = ev.x
                mLastMotionY = ev.y
                return !childViewGroup.isViewInBounds(ev.rawX.toInt(), ev.rawY.toInt())
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun View.isViewInBounds(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean {
        val location = IntArray(2)
        getLocationOnScreen(location)
        val left = location[0]
        val top = location[1]
        val right = left + width
        val bottom = top + height
        return x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom
    }
}

class ParentAdapter : ListAdapter<ParentItem, ParentAdapter.ParentViewHolder>(diffUtil) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ParentViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind()
    }

    inner class ParentViewHolder(val binding: ItemRecyclerviewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        lateinit var childAdapter: ChildAdapter

        init {
            binding.root.findViewById<TouchThroughConstraintLayout>(R.id.touchThroughLayout).setChildView(binding.childRecyclerView)
        }

        fun bind() = with(binding) {
            childRecyclerView.apply {
                childAdapter = ChildAdapter()
                adapter = childAdapter
            }

            childAdapter.submitList(arrayListOf(
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
            ))
        }

    }

    companion object {
        val diffUtil = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ParentItem>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ParentItem, newItem: ParentItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ParentItem, newItem: ParentItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.nestedrecyclerviewtouchevent.TouchThroughConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/touchThroughLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sbg_white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/childRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</com.example.nestedrecyclerviewtouchevent.TouchThroughConstraintLayout>


Which ChildView do you say? the one in ChildRecyclerView?

the issue you are encountering is that the isViewInBounds() method always returns true, causing the parent view to intercept the touch event. So here childRecyclerView (child view) touch events you can get.

Have made some changes in the gist

First of all, Thank you Akshay! It was good code but When i touch the childRecyclerView, the touch effect doesn't work.

Finally, I could made it. First of all, Thank you ltp and Akshay. You guys gave me a lot of inspiration.
Before we go any further,Let's recap. 
What did I want? 

When i click(touch) everywhere on the ParentViewholder, the touch effect shows up even if i touch the child RecyclerView.
when i swipe(scroll) the child RecyclerView, i can scroll the rv but the touch effect on the ParentViewHolder doesn't have to show up. 

NOTE: This code would be not perfect.
MainActivity 
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding by lazy {
        ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val parentAdapter = ParentAdapter()
        binding.parentRecyclerView.apply {
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL))
            adapter = parentAdapter
            itemAnimator = null
        }

        parentAdapter.submitList(arrayListOf(
            ParentItem(),
            ParentItem(),
            .... // some items...
            ParentItem(),
        ))

    }
}

activity_main
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parentRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

ParentAdapter
data class ParentItem(
    val name: String = ""
)

class ParentAdapter: ListAdapter<ParentItem, ParentAdapter.ParentViewHolder>(diffUtil) {

    private var selectedPosition = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ParentViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        val holder = ParentViewHolder(binding)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            notifyItemChanged(holder.adapterPosition, true)
            true
        }

        return holder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: ParentViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            holder.bindForClick()
            return
        }

        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(selectedPosition)
    }

    class ParentViewHolder(val binding: ItemRecyclerviewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        lateinit var childAdapter: ChildAdapter

        init {
            binding.root.setChildView(binding.childRecyclerView)
        }

        fun bindForClick() {
            itemView.isSelected = true
            itemView.postDelayed({
                itemView.isSelected = false
            }, 100)

        }

        fun bind(selectedPosition: Int) = with(binding) {
            childRecyclerView.apply {
                childAdapter = ChildAdapter()
                adapter = childAdapter
            }

            childAdapter.submitList(arrayListOf(
                HashTag(),
                HashTag(),
                ... // some items...
                HashTag(),
            ))
        }

    }

    companion object {
        val diffUtil = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ParentItem>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ParentItem, newItem: ParentItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ParentItem, newItem: ParentItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

        }
    }

}

item_recyclerview.xml(for ParentAdapter Viewholder)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.nestedtouchthroughrecyclerview.TouchThroughConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/touchThroughLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sbg_white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/childRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</dcom.example.nestedtouchthroughrecyclerview.TouchThroughConstraintLayout>

ChildAdapter
data class HashTag(
    val hashTags: List<String> = arrayListOf("noodle", "ramen", "meat", "cake", "happy", "skate", "castle"),
)

class ChildAdapter : ListAdapter<HashTag, ChildAdapter.ChildViewHolder>(diffUtil) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChildViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemHashtagBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ChildViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    class ChildViewHolder(val binding: ItemHashtagBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: HashTag) {
            binding.tvHashTag.text = "cake"
        }

    }

    companion object {
        val diffUtil = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HashTag>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: HashTag, newItem: HashTag): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: HashTag, newItem: HashTag): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

        }
    }

}

item_hashtag.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tvHashTag"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_hashtag_btn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingHorizontal="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    tools:text="test"
    tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

bg_hashtag.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#e6e6e6"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <size android:width="30dp" android:height="15dp" />
</shape>

sbg_white.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#EAEAEA" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF1F1F1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
<!--    <item android:state_pressed="true">-->
<!--        <shape android:shape="rectangle">-->
<!--            <solid android:color="#FFF1F1F1"/>-->
<!--        </shape>-->
<!--    </item>-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

